# How to convert List of List String into List of List Integer in java

Tags: java, list

I have a List of List string, now I want to convert it into List of List Integer. Suggest some way, How to proceed for it?

here is my code:

```
public class convert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            List<List<String>> outerList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            outerList.add(new ArrayList<String>(asList("11","2")));
            outerList.add(new ArrayList<String>(asList("2","1")));
            outerList.add(new ArrayList<String>(asList("11","3")));

            System.out.println(outerList);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to iterate over each `subItem` of each `item`.

```
List<List<String>> stringList = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); // Input
List<List<Integer>> intList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(); // Output
for (List<String> item : stringList) {
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String subItem : item) {
        temp.add(Integer.parseInt(subItem));
    }
    intList.add(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I woud suggest using the Streams API for this:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

...

integerList = outerList.stream()
   .map(innerList->innerList.stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(toList()))
   .collect(toList());
```

Comment: This also works, can you tell how your appraoch differ from rest of the replies I got. I mean, can use of **map** add some difference  in term of performance.

Comment: Main difference is that this is Java 8, while other answers also work with previous versions of Java

Comment: The approach differs from others in that it is more concise and more readable because it states the intent rather than going through the mechanics of achieving it. In terms of performance you can expect a very marginal overhead, which is very probably dwarfed by the computation going on in `Integer::valueOf`.

Answer (score 3):

You simply try like this:

```
for(String s : yourStringList) 
{
  intList.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
}
```

EDIT

```
for (List<String> s : yourStringList) {
    List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String str: s) {
        x.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
    }
    intList.add(x);
}
```

Comment: +1. Maybe enclose in `{ }` and add a little validation in there?

Answer (score 1):

res is new arrayList contains lists of integers.

```
       List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

        for(List<String> l : outerList){
            ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(String s: l){
                al.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
            }
            res.add(al);
        }
```